# Android viewpager actual default offscreen page limit

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have implemented simple ViewPager with its pager adapter.PagerAdapter takes list of views to displaye in ViewPager.I have not called setOffscreenPageLimit for ViewPager to set limit.
So by default 1 limit is selected.(1 page should be retained to either side of the current page in an idle state).But in actual there are 2 pages retained to either side.

```
0 | 1 | 2(current visible) | 3 | 4
```

Could you please confirm why it is happening?

Comment: "there are 2 pages retained to either side" -- how do you know that this is true? what variable or objects are you looking at? thanks!

Comment: At idle state I checked container.getChildCount() (used in instantiateItem method in PagerAdapter) which gives 5.That means there are 2 pages retained to either side.

Comment: i tried to reproduce this behavior with a simple fragment containing a ListView, using android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter and android.support.v4.view.ViewPager but container.getChildCount always remained 3 or lower in my test app. are you using the same ViewPager class i'm using?

Comment: i'll post the code i'm using below ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce this behavior, but with the following code I see container.getChildCount() always 3 or lower:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String TAG = SectionsPagerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            Log.v(TAG, "container.getChildCount:" + container.getChildCount());
            return super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 10;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            return String.format(l, "Section %d", position);
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {}

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            listAdapter.add("Fragment Body " + getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
            listAdapter.add("one");
            listAdapter.add("two");
            listAdapter.add("three");
            listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same behaviour, and finally found it will only occur when ViewPager's horizontal padding has been set to none zero value.

In this case, offscreenPageLimit is 1, which means ViewPager should fill content area (which width is ViewPager's width multiplied 3) with child pager views (each pager's width is ViewPager's width minus horizontal paddings), so the finally needed page count is

```
3 * ViewPager.getWidth() / (ViewPager.getWidth() - ViewPager.getPaddingLeft() - ViewPager.getPaddingRight()) > 3
```

Then ViewPager's current implementation may think it need 5 page to fill the content area.

This should a bug of ViewPager because it can optimize the above logic as 3 page is enough to fill the content area.